# How to Parse a JSON Object in Oracle APEX v5.1 that is Stored within an Array

Tags: javascript, json, oracle-apex

I have the following sample JSON Object array, i.e.:

```
[
{
"type": "Campaign",
"currentStatus": "Active",
"id": "206",
"depth": "complete",
"folderId": "1428",
"name": "Car Loan",
"isReadOnly": "false"
},
{
"type": "Debate",
"currentStatus": "Active",
"id": "207",
"depth": "pending",
"folderId": "1429",
"name": "House Loan",
"isReadOnly": "true"
}
]
```

Based on the above, I am unsure how to iterate through each of these JSON objects, inside this array?

For each object, I then need to produce a report showing all columns for these two JSON object records.

I've looked at `apex_json.get_count` but unsure how to apply to this array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 12c database you could use json_table like:
(As far as I know you need a parent tag. In the example I used "row")

```
SELECT jsn.*
  FROM   JSON_TABLE('{"row":[{"type": "Campaign","currentStatus": "Active","id": "206","depth": "complete","folderId": "1428","name": "Car Loan","isReadOnly": "false"},{"type": "Debate","currentStatus": "Active","id": "207","depth": "pending","folderId": "1429","name": "House Loan","isReadOnly": "true"}] }'
             , '$.row[*]'
     COLUMNS (type          VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.type',
              currentStatus VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.currentStatus',
              id            VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.id',
              depth         VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.depth',
              folderId      VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.folderId',
              name          VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.name',
              isReadOnly    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.isReadOnly')) jsn;
```

If you are **not** using 12c database you could use apex_json. In order to use it in a report a pipeline function could be an option like:

```
-- Create the types to support the table function.
DROP TYPE t_tf_tab;
DROP TYPE t_tf_row;

CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT (
  type          varchar2(50),
  currentStatus varchar2(50),
  id            varchar2(50),
  depth         varchar2(50),
  folderId      varchar2(50),
  name          varchar2(50),
  isReadOnly    varchar2(50)
);
/

CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;
/

-- Build the table function itself.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_tf RETURN t_tf_tab AS
  l_tab  t_tf_tab := t_tf_tab();
  l_json CLOB := '{"row": [ {
                                "type": "Campaign",
                                "currentStatus": "Active",
                                "id": "206",
                                "depth": "complete",
                                "folderId": "1428",
                                "name": "Car Loan",
                                "isReadOnly": "false"
                                },
                                {
                                "type": "Debate",
                                "currentStatus": "Active",
                                "id": "207",
                                "depth": "pending",
                                "folderId": "1429",
                                "name": "House Loan",
                                "isReadOnly": "true"
                                }
                                ] }';

     j apex_json.t_values;
     l_path  VARCHAR2(100);

    BEGIN
      apex_json.parse(l_json);

      FOR i IN 1..apex_json.get_count(p_path   => 'row')
      LOOP
        l_tab.extend;
        l_tab(l_tab.last) := t_tf_row( apex_json.get_varchar2( p_path => 'row[%d].type', p0 => i),
                                       apex_json.get_varchar2( p_path => 'row[%d].currentStatus', p0 => i),
                                       apex_json.get_varchar2( p_path => 'row[%d].id', p0 => i),
                                       apex_json.get_varchar2( p_path => 'row[%d].depth', p0 => i),
                                       apex_json.get_varchar2( p_path => 'row[%d].folderId', p0 => i),
                                       apex_json.get_varchar2( p_path => 'row[%d].name', p0 => i),
                                       apex_json.get_varchar2( p_path => 'row[%d].isReadOnly', p0 => i)
                                     );
      END LOOP;

  RETURN l_tab;
END;
/

-- Test it.
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(get_tab_tf)
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I'm not sure where the {"row": is coming from as my JSON array object purely starts with just [{ so if possible, could you please update your answer to reflect this JSON format which also ends with }]

Comment: As far as I know you need a path in order to go through the json structure and I assumed you could modify the json.

As an alternative if you remove the outside "{ }" my solution can also be applied with small changes. Maybe this could be a better solution since a replace for the first and last "{" "}" would be easy to do: 
     l_json := regexp_replace(l_json, '^[ ]*{(.*)}[ ]*$', '\1')

If you want I can update the solution using this approach.

Comment: no problems - that's fine but thanks for the alternative. still investigating.